# Work Manager on Android versions bellow OREO

Tags: android, notifications, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I am using Work Manager in my app. It enqueues the work like that:

```
fun makeNotificationRequest() {

    val notificationWork = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationWorker::class.java)
            .setInitialDelay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addTag(NOTIFICATION_TAG)
            .build()
    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(notificationWork)
}
```

Here is my Worker Class:

```
class NotificationWorker : Worker() {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        makeNotification()
        return Worker.Result.SUCCESS
}}
```

On Android API OREO and higher even if app is killed my notification is triggered. But If API below OREO - notification won't trigger in killed application. 
What should I do to trigger my notification in old versions of Android? Or Worker works only in OREO and higher? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Worker Manager is backward compatible upto API 19.

Worker Manager is oem dependent (it's still in beta version). If the advanced optimisation is switched on in some devices work manager is also not triggered when the app is not running. The work around for this would be to use **JobIntentService** for below Oreo devices and worker manager for Oreo and above devices(the problem will still be persistent if advanced optimisation is on for these devices).

Or you can promt the user turn down the optimisation for your app.